# (Flutter) Android Navigation bar does not disappear after some time when swiped from below

Tags: android, flutter, dart, navigationbar, flutter-bottomnavigation

I want users to still see the status bar so I have done it like this:

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
      SystemUiMode.manual,
      overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top],
    );
  }
```

When user swipes from below, the navigation appears, but does not go away. How should I address this issue? Or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Kindly Attach Error Picture ?

Comment: There's no error as such. But the navigation bar doesn't disappear after it's accessed for the first time @MobinAnsar

Answer (score -1):

Kindly Read this [Documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/fullscreen_mode)

Comment: package is deprecated